# Shadow on dynamic line of table

Tags: html, css, symfony

I'm trying to put a shadow on each one of my table lines. But it's not working with the first one and I don't really understand why.

I put you the css inline as you can see the all things

```
{% for resultat in resultats %}
    <tr style="background-color: #F0F0F0; box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #aaa, 8px -8px 12px #aaa; -webkit-box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #aaa;" 
    id="first_{{ nb }}>
        <td>
            <span class="fl marginTop8">
                {{ resultat.missions.getDateReaPrev()|date('Y-m-d') }}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <span class="fl marginTop8">
                {{ resultat.distance }} Km
            </span>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="badge fr" style="color: darkorange;">{{ resultat.nb_pdv }}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color:white">
        <td colspan="6"></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is what I got with this code:

[image: array]

As you can see, the shadow is on the right both tr...but the border is only on the last tr.

I would like to get something like this one

[image: array2]

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: For more precision there is a class tableEnquete on the table.

So there is too

```
.tableEnquetes tr:nth-child(2){ position:relative }

.tableEnquetes table{
    border-radius: 0 0 15px 0;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #AAA;
    margin: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
 }
```

Here is a fiddle of this problem: https://jsfiddle.net/wdwgn7ta/

Comment: Can you paste your css? If is possible paste all necesary code on a jsfiddle

Comment: Also: by code we mean the generated markup, since this is purely a cosmetic issue and we don't need to know the loop you're using to generate the final markup.

Comment: I added some information about the css...there is no more and what I added by myself is inline on the tr. This part is concerning the grey row, the orange one is the th.

Comment: I added a fiddle too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change `background-color:white` to `background-color:none`

```
<tr style="background-color:none">
    <td colspan="6"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed. I wouldn't have imagined the white row override the shadow :( Thanks again !